# PHP Imap - Count Number of Emails From Today

Tags: php, email, imap

I need to get the number of emails that are in a gmail inbox from todays date only.

So far I have used this to only get emails from todays date:

```
$todaysEmails = imap_search($mbox,'ON "'.$date.'"');
```

And I have tried combining it with this to count the number of emails:

```
$numEmails = imap_num_msg($todaysEmails);
```

However this returns an error:

> PHP Warning:  imap_num_msg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/html/getAttachment.php on line 7

How can I go about achieving this correctly?

Comment: $date = date("j F Y");

Comment: imap_num_msg does a server query of how many messages are in a folder, not a search result.  Presumably you just want to take the length of $todays_email.

Comment: Max, "take the length"?? Maybe you could post the code you had in mind. Tha would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date must be formatted in this format: "13 Jun 2017"

`$date = date("j F Y");`

Answer (score 0):

You have two things that need to be fixed, the date needs to be formatted properly and just use count function to give you the number of items in the $todaysEmails array.

```
$date = date("j F Y");
$todaysEmails = imap_search($mbox,'ON "'.$date.'"');
$numEmails = count($todaysEmails);
echo "Today's email total : ".$numEmails;
```